# Django, gevent-socketio and sessions

Tags: javascript, python, django, socket.io

Im developing a turn-based game with Django and gevent-socketio. I have the Socket.IO server implemented in a python module (game_socketio.py), a class (GameNamespace) that have methods to emit and receive messages/events between the JS client. Now I need to integrate the auth/sessions system with this websockets interactions, in order to return user model info to the javascript client via Socket.IO.

It would be useful to have the request object or session variables present in the GameNamespace class, so, there is a way to pass this object? I'm not constructing it the views.

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I just read in __init__.py, in the socketio module this: It will simply be attached to the Socket and Namespace object (accessible through ``self.request`` in both cases). I can access the request object in the Namespace class, via self.request :)

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept your answer. This way other users of Stack Overflow see that the problem is solved. If you don't want to do this, please delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

[gevent-socketio](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio)'s `namespace` already have session (dict) and request as its parameter.